# Hausdorff dimension of F and f(F)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis, dimensional-analysis

We have F being a subset of R, [-1,1], while f:R->R, where f(x)=x^2.
What's the Hausdorff dimension of F and f(F)? I think the dim(F)=2(length) and dim(f(F))=1, is it correct? Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean Hausdorff dimension or Hausdorff measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not correct. Any interval (of any lenght) has Hausdorff dimension 1. The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension) has measure zero and Hausdorff dimension $\log_3(2)$.